# Too many open mongoDB connections when using Celery

Tags: mongodb, celery, mongoengine, django-celery

I'm using Celery to download feeds and resize images. The feeds and image paths are then stored in MongoDB using mongoengine. When I check current connections (db.serverStatus()["connections"]) after running the tasks I have between 50-80 "current" connections, which remain open until I shutdown celeryd. Has anyone experienced this issue and/or do you know what I can do to solve it?

Thanks,
Kenzic

Comment: I think that this can't be a celery problem, at the end everything depends from the code that you write in your task. Check careful it and I'm sure that you will solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This just means that there are between 50 and 80 connections open to the MongoDB server, and isn't cause for concern. PyMongo (and therefore MongoEngine) maintain an internal pool of connections (that is, sockets) to `mongod`, so even when nothing is happening (no active queries, commands, etc), the connections remain open to the database for the next time they will be used. By default, PyMongo attempts to retain no more than 10 open connections per `Connection` object.

Are you experiencing any specific problems due to the number of open connections?

Comment: I'm not experiencing any specific problems but because i'm new to PyMongo, I was concerned by the number. Thanks for the response, it was helpful!